# Linear Programming objective function

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

Is it possible for a certain variable to have zero coefficient at objective function ?

For example, can I have

Z= x while my decision variable is x and y?

Comment: Yes, You can even make all objective coefficients zero, In that case the LP solver will stop as soon as a feasible solution is found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in fact this is a frequent situation. You can thus define utility variables to use for your constraints only.

Comment: If the coefficient of y is zero at objective function, this means no matter what the value of y is, the optimal value is unaffected right ?

Comment: This is not necessarily true. Consider the problem $\min y$ subject to $y\geqslant x$ and $x,y\geqslant0$. The coefficient of the variable $x$ in the objective function is zero, but if we set $x=5$, the optimal objective value is $5$, while if we set $x=10$, the optimal objective value is $10$.